# Do I need to free the result of strerror() in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

To my understanding, `strerror(errno)` returns the string form of the error corresponding to `errno`. In that case, do I need to free the returned result of the function once I finished using it?

Comment: No.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror

Comment: It's a good question because strerror() returns "char*" and not "const char*". That's strange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not only do you not *need to*; you **must not**. The only things you can pass to `free` are pointers to memory you obtained by `malloc` or a function specified to return memory obtain by `malloc` or "as if by `malloc`". There is no such text in the specification of `strerror`, so passing the string it returns to `free` would produce undefined behavior. In particular, if the implementation uses `malloc` internally to obtain the memory, you would be freeing that memory out from under it, causing it to perform use-after-free or double-free, which are some of the most dangerous types of memory bugs.

In practice, `strerror` usually returns immutable strings from libc `.rodata` or from a `mmap`ped translation file, and it's likely that the error would immediately be caught as a crash.

Comment: strerror() returns "char*" and not "const char*". So when you say the string is immutable that can't be right.

Comment: @somega: The qualification of the pointed-to type for a pointer has nothing to do with whether what it points to can be modified. `char *` can point to `const char` or to (an element of) a `char []` array that is not modifiable (e.g. because it's a string literal). Whether you're permitted to modify something is a matter of the language specification and interface contract of the function that gave you the pointer, not the type.

Comment: Do you have an explanation why it is defined as "char*" and not as "const char*"?

Comment: @somega: Because lots of C code is not const-correct and would produce warnings (should be errors) due to things like `char *msg = strerror(errno);` Historically C did not even have the `const` keyword, and `strerror` likely even predates the addition of `const`. It's a normal idiom for functions to return non-const-qualified pointers like this, and necessary for some like `strchr` where whether the object is modifiable depends on what you passed in.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `strerror` does **not** need to be free'ed.  It typically points to a read-only string or a static buffer.  Because of this, this function is not considered thread safe.

There is a related function called `strerror_r`, which takes a user specified buffer and its size and fills the buffer with the error message.  This function is thread safe.