# 'Invalid utf-8 sequence of 1 bytes from index 1' and 'munmup_chunk(): invalid pointer' error in my Rust unit-tests

Tags: linux, rust, system-calls, glibc, unsafe-pointers

There`s only lib.rs file:

```
use libc::{self, O_RDONLY, strerror, open, close, __errno_location, read};
use std::ffi::{CString, CStr};
use std::{fmt, process};

// File descriptor
struct Fd {
    fd: i32,
}

impl Fd {
    fn new(fd: i32) -> Fd {
        Fd { fd }
    }

    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        self.fd
    }
}

impl Drop for Fd {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            println!("closing fd - {}", self.fd);
            match close(self.fd) {
                -1 => Err( LacError::new().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
                        eprintln!("{}", e);
                        process::exit(1); 
                    }) ).unwrap_or_else(|e| {
                        eprintln!("{}", e);
                        process::exit(1);}),
                _ => (),
            }
        }
    }
}

// Linux API call Error
#[derive(Debug)]
struct LacError(String);

impl LacError {
    fn new() -> Result<LacError, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        unsafe {
            Ok( LacError( CString::from_raw(strerror(*__errno_location()))
                .into_string()?) )
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for LacError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for LacError {}

// lac (Linux API call) functions
fn lac_open(path: &str) -> Result<Fd, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    unsafe {
        let path_holder = CString::new(path)?;
        let path_ptr = path_holder.as_ptr();

        match open(path_ptr, O_RDONLY) {
            -1 => Err(Box::new(LacError::new()?)),
            fd => Ok(Fd::new(fd)) 
        }
    }
}

fn lac_read(fd: &Fd,
            buf: &mut String,
            count: usize) -> Result<isize, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>  {
    let buf_holder = CString::new("")?;
    let buf_ptr = buf_holder.as_ptr();

    unsafe {
        match read(fd.get(), buf_ptr as *mut libc::c_void, count) {
            0 => Ok(0),
            -1 => Err(Box::new(LacError::new()?)),
            num_of_red_bytes => {
                buf.push_str(CStr::from_ptr(buf_ptr).to_str()?);
                Ok(num_of_red_bytes)
            },
        }
    }
}    
 
// TESTS
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn whether_correctly_open() {
        let path = "test_file.txt";
        assert_ne!(match lac_open(path) {Ok(fd) => fd.get(), Err(_) => -1},
        -1);
    }

    #[test]
    #[should_panic]
    fn whether_correctly_panic() {
        let path = "testfile.txt";// For first issue "testfile.txt", for second "test_file.txt"
        match lac_open(path) {
            Ok(_) => (),
            Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn whether_correctly_read() {
        let path = "test_file.txt"; 
        let mut buf = String::from("");

        let fd = lac_open(path)
            .unwrap_or_else(|e| {panic!("{}", e);});
        let count = lac_read(&fd, &mut buf, 1)
            .unwrap_or_else(|e| {panic!("{}", e);});
        println!("{} {}", buf, count);
        assert_eq!(buf, "s"); 
    }
}
```

At first when I run 'cargo test -- -show-output' first test passes successfully but second (third test omit for a while) not just fails (

```
running 3 tests
test tests::whether_correctly_open ... ok
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
error: test failed, to rerun pass '--lib'

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `/home/Michail/rPrgs/usl/target/debug/deps/usl-1be62c27ff5543fb --show-output` (signal: 6, SIGABRT: process abort signal)
```

) OS dispatch signal to that process probably because of operations in `LacError::new()`-method:

```
impl LacError {
    fn new() -> Result<LacError, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        unsafe {
            Ok( LacError( CString::from_raw(strerror(*__errno_location()))
                .into_string()?) )
        }
    }
}
```

And I exactly don`t know where I make a mistake.

At second, when I swap "testfile.txt" with "test_file.txt" and made second test really fail I run 'cargo test -- --show-output' and (I believe `cause 'cargo test' run in few threads by default) receive

```
running 3 tests
test tests::whether_correctly_open ... ok
test tests::whether_correctly_panic ... FAILED
test tests::whether_correctly_read ... ok

successes:

---- tests::whether_correctly_open stdout ----
closing fd - 3

---- tests::whether_correctly_read stdout ----
s 1
closing fd - 3


successes:
    tests::whether_correctly_open
    tests::whether_correctly_read

failures:

---- tests::whether_correctly_panic stdout ----
closing fd - 3
note: test did not panic as expected

failures:
    tests::whether_correctly_panic

test result: FAILED. 2 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

error: test failed, to rerun pass '--lib'
```

and if few times run

```
test tests::whether_correctly_open ... ok
test tests::whether_correctly_panic ... FAILED
test tests::whether_correctly_read ... FAILED

successes:

---- tests::whether_correctly_open stdout ----
closing fd - 3


successes:
    tests::whether_correctly_open

failures:

---- tests::whether_correctly_panic stdout ----
closing fd - 3
note: test did not panic as expected
---- tests::whether_correctly_read stdout ----
thread 'tests::whether_correctly_read' panicked at 'invalid utf-8 sequence of 1 bytes from index 2', src/lib.rs:119:34
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
closing fd - 3


failures:
    tests::whether_correctly_panic
    tests::whether_correctly_read

test result: FAILED. 1 passed; 2 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

error: test failed, to rerun pass '--lib'
```

that is, over time when I repeat run command from above I receive different results. That issue with utf-8 as I think relate to that code

```
fn lac_read(fd: &Fd,
            buf: &mut String,
            count: usize) -> Result<isize, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>  {
    let buf_holder = CString::new("")?;
    let buf_ptr = buf_holder.as_ptr();

    unsafe {
        match read(fd.get(), buf_ptr as *mut libc::c_void, count) {
            0 => Ok(0),
            -1 => Err(Box::new(LacError::new()?)),
            num_of_red_bytes => {
                buf.push_str(CStr::from_ptr(buf_ptr).to_str()?);//<-----------------------
                Ok(num_of_red_bytes)
            },
        }
    }
}
```

In addition when I repeatly run 'cargo test -- --show-output --test-threads=1' third test always fails.

UPD: Before tests I wrote common latin chars in "test_file.txt" via

```
echo sometext > test_file.txt
```

**Final UPDate**: First issue I decided just by creating new owned String from borrowed strerror string:

```
impl LacError {
    fn new() -> Result<LacError, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        unsafe {
            Ok( LacError( String::from( CStr::from_ptr(strerror(*__errno_location())).to_str()? ) ) )
        }
    }
}
```

And second is most interesting, because CString is not growable string and read syscall inserts chars into spaces. I decided write `for` loop for pushing 'count' number of spaces in temporary 'container' that is growable owned string:

```
fn lac_read(fd: &Fd,
            buf: &mut String,
            count: usize) -> Result<isize, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>  {
    let mut container = String::new();
    for _ in 0..count {
        container.push(' ');
    }
    let buf_holder = CString::new(container.as_str())?;
    let buf_ptr = buf_holder.into_raw();

    unsafe {
        match read(fd.get(), buf_ptr as *mut libc::c_void, count) {
            0 => Ok(0),
            -1 => Err(Box::new(LacError::new()?)),
            num_of_red_bytes => {
                buf.push_str(CString::from_raw(buf_ptr).to_str()?);
                Ok(num_of_red_bytes)
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `CString` will try to de-allocate its string when it goes out of scope. Instead you should use `CStr` which will not do it:

```
impl LacError {
    fn new() -> Result<LacError, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        unsafe {
            Ok(LacError(
                CStr::from_ptr(strerror(*__errno_location())).to_string_lossy().to_string()
            ))
        }
    }
}
```

Usually whoever creates/allocates/etc is responsible for the destruction/de-allocation/etc, unless it's explicitly stated otherwise by the docs. As the string was allocated by the OS, [it's an error to try to de-allocate it from the application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62273040/2588800).

#### The next question: why does your third test fail:

The `read()` call reads up to `count` number of bytes into the provided buffer. But it **DOES NOT** resize the buffer. Your application creates a buffer of size 1 (it's 1, because C strings are 0 terminated):

```
let buf_holder = CString::new("")?;
```

The problem is that C strings **must be** 0 terminated. So if you read something that is not 0, `CStr::from_ptr()` will try to read from uninitialized memory outside of the buffer, which is undefined behaviour. You can make it 100% reproducible by changing the count:

```
let count = lac_read(&fd, &mut buf, 100).unwrap();
```

Now your app will try to read 100 bytes into that 1 byte buffer, corrupting everything after it. With that I always get:

```
malloc(): corrupted top size
```

So in order to fix the issue, you must make sure that your buffer is large enough to hold the data (and do not forget the trailing 0!)

Comment: Ok, but leaves second part of problem. I think I should much more dig std docs.

Comment: Does CStr implement into_string?

Comment: @Michail No, it does not, because the C string is not necessarily valid UTF. Instead it implements https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.to_string_lossy

Comment: Always works with CString::new(" "). I think I should write function that will insert 'count' number of spaces in &str argument in new() method.

Comment: Why do you use unsafe ? Rust has its own abstractions for reading/writing files ?